# How do I combine multiple lines for the same package? (SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I am doing an assignment and I am close to completing it. However the package balance appears on multiple lines and I would like to combine the balances for each package type.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('vwPackageRevenue') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW vwPackageRevenue
GO

CREATE VIEW vwPackageRevenue
AS
SELECT (dbo.packageWH.PNAME) AS 'Package Name'
    ,(COSTPERSON * COUNT(GFirstName)) AS 'Total Revenue'
FROM dbo.packageWH
JOIN dbo.reservationWH ON dbo.packageWH.P_ID = dbo.reservationWH.P_ID
JOIN guestWH ON dbo.reservationWH.RNUM = dbo.guestWH.RNUM
GROUP BY dbo.packageWH.COSTPERSON
    ,dbo.packageWH.PNAME
    ,dbo.guestWH.GFIRSTNAME 
GO

SELECT *
FROM vwPackageRevenue
```

Any ideas how to complete this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a `SUM` and I am not sure what the `>` signs are doing in there.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('vwPackageRevenue') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW vwPackageRevenue
GO

CREATE VIEW vwPackageRevenue
AS
SELECT (dbo.packageWH.PNAME) AS 'Package Name'
    ,SUM((COSTPERSON * COUNT(GFirstName)))  AS 'Total Revenue'
FROM dbo.packageWH
JOIN dbo.reservationWH ON  dbo.packageWH.P_ID = dbo.reservationWH.P_ID
JOIN guestWH ON dbo.reservationWH.RNUM = dbo.guestWH.RNUM
GROUP BY 
dbo.packageWH.PNAME

GO

SELECT *
FROM vwPackageRevenue
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: might need to tweak the group by clause as well, s/b just PNAME, I think.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanFite, that's probably right.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When trying this I got errors because it didn't like a COUNT function being within SUM. Also it would throw an error if I only had dbo.packageWH.PNAME within the GROUP BY clause. HOWEVER I have figured out the solution was simply removing dbo.guestWH.GFIRSTNAME from the GROUP BY clause from the previous code.